# Fazer uma consulta com pymongo filtrando por uma string ignorando letras maiusculas e minusculas

Tags: python, query, mongodb, pymongo, case-insensitive

Preciso fazer uma consulta em uma base de dados no MongoDB usando a biblioteca pymongo no python, a consulta que estou a fazer é a seguinte:

```
dbCliente.find({"nome": "carlos"})
```

Quero retornar o cliente cujo o nome seja exatamente "carlos" porém ignorando letras maiúsculas ou minusculas.

Como faço essa consulta usando pymongo?

Comment: Tenta com [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/reference/operator/query/regex/) :`dbCliente.find({"nome":{ $regex: 'carlos', $options: 'i' } })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O caminho mais correto seria criar um índice que seja case insensitive

### Criando a coleção

```
db.createCollection("nomes", { collation: { locale: 'pt_BR', strength: 2 } })
```

### Criando índice

```
db.nomes.createIndex( { nome: 1} )
```

### Inserindo nomes

```
db.nomes.insert( [ { nome: "Carlos" },
                   { nome: "CARLOS"},
                   { nome: "carlos"} ] )
```

### Buscando

```
db.nomes.find( { nome: "carlos" } )
```

**Nota**: irá encontrar os três resultados

No seu caso, você poderá usar

```
dbCliente.find({"nome": "carlos"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra maneira é utilizando o módulo re, que inclui opções para expressões regulares:

```
import re
dbCliente.find({"nome": re.compile("carlos", re.IGNORECASE))
```